# The web application do not function properly after using the sencha build command

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, extjs, web, sencha-cmd

I am using the asp.net mvc4 as the back-end and the extjs 4.2.1 as the front-end. After finish the developing, I use the *sencha app build* of the sencha cmd to pack the front-end code to production. ALL is working just ok, but when I press one specific button in my web app, there is an error indicating that "e.redraw() is not a function". In my development environment, it works properly. So, I wonder why the error could even occur because I did not change any section of the code.

I did not obey the scaffolding of sencha cmd(sencha -sdk pathToSdk generate app Test pathToApp, then add models, views or controller using the specific command)
Below is my workflow:

1. when develop, I follow the best practice of extjs's official documentation.
2. using *sencha -sdk pathToSdk generate app Test pathToApp* to generate a template app. and then create every view and controller using the *sencha generate controller testController* and *sencha generate view testView* command. Then I copy all the content of my previous file into the newly created files. I did not do this to the models' file, because the model file has to be created like this *sencha generate model ID:int, name* which for me is not practical because I have 30 more fields in one of my model file. So I copy all the files located in my app/model directly to the template app's model directory.
3. using the sencha app build to build the process. and the copy the app.js and the resources directory in the production directory to my previous path, and then add the link and script tag in the Index.cshtml.

Above is my workflow, i have no idea why I can not make this.

Answer (score 0):

you can debug you build app and got the root cause of issue.

Run this command > Sencha app build testing.
Now Build file will create in your build/Testing folder.

You can use app.js file from here and easily debug.

yeah sometimes it happens that some config does not works after build.

try this e.config.redraw().

Comment: i use the sencha app build testing with more errors occuring. something like Ext.addListener call back function not found.

Comment: anyway, do you have any idea what is the best practice to use sencha cmd to an existing application. I don know why there are so many errors ahead.

Comment: Which Ext version and Sencha version are you using?